# how to update scan Cython code in Theano?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, theano, patch

when I use following ways to update ,there is some problem, system told me "missing header for unified diff at line 1 of patch

```
cd theano/scan_module/
cython scan_perform.pyx
patch scan_perform.c numpy_api_changes.diff
```

[image]

by the way, the reason I want to update is that when I used theano in windows anaconda environment, system told me "UserWarning: The file scan_perform.c is not available. This donot happen normally." I find the above method at:https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/scan_module/scan_perform_ext.py
then use following ways install patch command

```
conda install patch
```

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to disable this warning by following these steps:

1. Go to the [releases page](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/releases) of Theano, click on the commit hash corresponding to the version of Theano you have installed, and then on "Browse Files". In my case, since I have Theano 1.0.3, I used the hash [`65fefc3`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/tree/65fefc3acbdbc498e09ea6c6fa8143e2b14dd9e8).
2. Navigate to `theano/scan_module/c_code` in the github repo (corresponding to [this](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/tree/65fefc3acbdbc498e09ea6c6fa8143e2b14dd9e8/theano/scan_module/c_code) URL in my case), and download the contents of the file `scan_perform.c` into a file with the same name.
3. Go to wherever the Theano source files are located in your machine. In my case since I was using anaconda they were in:

   ```
   /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano
   ```
4. Once there, navigate to the `scan_module` directory, create a directory called `c_code`, and `cd` into it.
5. Paste the `scan_perform.c` file you just downloaded into this directory.

When executing Theano again you shouldn't see the warning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Upgrading to [theano 1.0.5](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/theano) solved the issue.